# Not able to boot from Kali after moved to SSD

Tags: linux, boot, ssd, grub, kali-linux

I thought of moving my kali linux to SSD. For that

1. I copied the whole existing Kali files hierarchy to the SSD partition.
2. Updated the /etc/fstab file with UUID of SSD partition.
3. Updated the grub.

I got the entry for ssd partition containing the kali.

However, when i tried to boot from ssd, I am still in my old system from HDD.

Can anyone help me regarding this? What i am missing here?

ps: i refered and old post saying that i need to update /boot/grub/menu.conf file but my system does not have that file

Edit1: I am booting in UEFI mode.

Comment: Are you booting in UEFI or legacy mode?

Comment: Booting in UEFI mode.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI boot entries to point to the SSD?

Comment: Well, i updated the grub but dont know how to update uefi entries. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike BIOS, which used boot records in known locations on the disk, UEFI uses a combination of filesystem contents on disk partitions and a list of boot entries. It's essentially a boot manager built into firmware. These entries are editable from an OS (`efibootmgr` on Linux), but it's easier to manage them through UEFI setup.

The list is usually available in the *Boot* section. How you access UEFI itself differs between motherboard manufacturers, but it's usually <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd> on the boot screen. `fwsetup` on the GRUB command line should work too.

Your goal is to add an entry for GRUB on the new disk and put it first on the list. Then save and reboot.